# Determine if the infinite series converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sum {\frac{n-2}{n\sqrt{4n+2}}}
\end{equation}
Which test suits the best for determing the convergence/divergence of this series?

I tried the Ratio test,the Limit comparison with ${\frac{1}{n}}$ and with ${\frac{1}{n^2}}$, I can't seem to find a "bigger" series that converges to use the Direct Comparison test and all of them with no result. I can't use the root test.

Any hint on how to get started on this one is appreciated.
Thanks in prior

Comment: Compare the summand to $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. The series diverges.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I didn't see this one coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to think about this: Constants don't mean anything compared to the growth of $n^p$ for any $p>0.$ Thus instead of

$$\sum \frac{n-2}{n\sqrt {4n+2}},$$

think about

$$\sum \frac{n}{n\sqrt {n}} = \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt {n}}.$$

Since the last series diverges, your guess should be "divergence" for the original series. That's the way calculus experts think about this. You still have to make sure your guess is correct, but instead of wandering around in the darkness, you have a good guide for the "first guess," and that is often the hardest part.

Comment: This just made my calculus easier for the rest of the semester. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 4$, $n-2\ge\frac{n}{2}$ while $4n+2\le\frac{9n}{2}$, so $\frac{n-2}{n\sqrt{4n+2}}\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{18n}}$. This confirms divergence.

Comment: +1 definitely and thank you for your help. But comparing with $n^-0.5$ seems clearer for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simpler way is to note that

$$\frac{n-2}{n\sqrt{4n+2}}\sim\frac{n}{n\sqrt{4n}}=\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$

and then refer to [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac1{\sqrt n}$.